# SharePoint 2013 Workflows not Associating with List

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow

On my SharePoint site I have 2 collections, '/' and '/sites/dev/'.

Everything works properly on the root site, but with with dev site collection any 2013 workflows that I publish are not being associated with the list they are created for.

I've used SharePoint Designer to create the workflow, and published to the list - but the workflow does not appear in the workflows section on the list in Designer or on the site (it does appear in the Workflows section of Designer though).

2010 workflows do publish correctly and are properly associated with the lists - so it's only the 2013 workflows that have the issue.

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Are you using list workflow or reusable workflow?

Comment: It is a list workflow.

Comment: Are you re creating your workflow for new site or using the same?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking @Aanchal? I am attempting to create simple new (list) workflows on both sites.

Comment: Have you tried with some other site?

Comment: I have tested on another site and the 2013 workflows do show up correctly there.

Comment: So that was another site collection?

Comment: Yes I have tested on another site collection, and another SharePoint install all together - both worked correctly.

Comment: Exact same think is happening to me - from what I have read it is due to the fact the site is custom. I have updated the forms via site ID and URL and they are now working fine but the 2013 workflows are not working. The old workflows have no list association. Researching a way to resolve this but nothing as yet.

Comment: I had the same issue - I published the workflow and it would not associate with the list. I had the list open in another window so I closed it, republished and now, finally, the workflow is associated with my list.

Comment: I am experiencing this after deleting a workflow and trying to add a different one. The most annoying issue ever

Answer (score 1):

Sometime this is because that the xoml and xsn files in the Sharepoint Designer (`Navigation -> All Files -> Wokflows -> Workflowname -> the *.xoml and *.xsn files`) are not checked in. There are couple of solutions: Clear SharePoint Designer Cache; Check Alternate Access Mapping; Check the required fields. For more information: [Click here](http://passionatetechie.blogspot.dk/2012/03/spd-workflow-error-solved-cannot.html)

Here is a [similar thread](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/127887.aspx?PageIndex=1) for you to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I've checked All Files -> Workflows to see if the files were checked out, but the 2013 workflow isn't showing up in that list. The second link seems more like the issue I am having, but there isn't an answer for their problem either - I have tried publishing from multiple computers and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you click on the workflow in SP designer, then edit the workflow.
SP Designer 2013->(Your Site)->Workflows->(Your Workflow)->Edit Workflow
At the top of the page under "edit workflow" you should see the "Publish" button.
Click this and then check you SP site for the workflow.
(Your SP Site)->(Your SP List)->List Settings->Workflow Settings

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your workflow already exists:

1. Use SPD to browse to the list you want the workflow associated to.
2. On the List Information screen, look for Workflows (A list of workflows associated with this list). Click on the blue title called "Workflows".
3. The workflow page has an option a the top to "Associate Existing Workflow". Clicking it  will open a browser window that allows you to select your workflow again.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling and Enabling the Feature 'WorkflowServiceStore' fixed it

```
Disable-SPFeature -Identity WorkflowServiceStore –Url $yourUrl
```

and

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity WorkflowServiceStore –Url $yourUrl
```

then just republish.