# Associated Workflow Not Applying to List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a list called `Expert Database` which always had 2 workflows, `New Expert` (to be run when a new item is added to the list) and `Expert Review Notification` (should run whenever an item is changed).

I recently deleted the `Expert Review Notification` workflow and created a new one called `Edit Expert` in SharePoint Designer by directly adding the workflow to the list (so it should automatically associated itself with the list).

After saving and publishing the workflow, does not appear under the list of associated workflows:

[image]

I have tried deleting the workflow and recreating it.

I also tried the solutions given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104440/sharepoint-2013-workflows-not-associating-with-list) with no effect, however when trying to find the `*.xoml` and `*.xsn` files in SharePoint Designer, I can't see any of my existing workflows in the `Workflows` folder:

[image]

And they do not appear in any of those folders. Does this perhaps indicate what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of if the workflow is not listed at workflow settings based on your workflow platform so that means the workflow **actually** has not been published.

[image]

So to trace your issue , I suggest to you to

- Create and publish a dummy workflow to another list ,
- Check if it's associated or not ?! if it's not associated and looks a general issue try to use another SharePoint designer that has been installed on another machine , make sure you have published your workflow , if it's working properly, so the issue at your SharePoint Designer , try to uninstall it , restart your machine, install it , this should solve the issue.

**Note :** I have considered you are following the alternative solution at [SharePoint 2013 Workflows not Associating with List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104440/sharepoint-2013-workflows-not-associating-with-list) as you mentioned at your question.